# Why does my child class stop inheriting from the default constructor of parent when I add a constructor?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have these classes with a main that compiles fine:

```c
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace ft {

    template < class T, class Diff >
    class iterator { };



    template < class T, class Diff >
    class iterator< const T*, Diff > {
    public:

        typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef const T                         value_type;
        typedef Diff                            difference_type;
        typedef value_type*                     pointer;
        typedef value_type&                     reference;

        constexpr iterator( void )
        noexcept
        :       m_data(nullptr)
        { cout << "parent default constructor called" << endl; }

        constexpr iterator( const iterator & other )
        noexcept
        :       m_data(other.m_data)
        { cout << "parent copy constructor called" << endl; }

    protected:

        pointer m_data;
    };



    template < class T, class Diff >
    class iterator< T*, Diff > : public iterator< const T*, Diff > {
    public:

        typedef T           value_type;
        typedef value_type* pointer;
        typedef value_type& reference;

        //constexpr explicit iterator( const pointer & ptr )
        //noexcept
        //:     m_data(ptr)
        //{ }

    private:

        pointer m_data;
    };



    template < class T, class Diff >
    using pointer_iterator = iterator< T*, Diff >;

    template < class T, class Diff >
    using pointer_const_iterator = iterator< const T*, Diff >;

}


int main( void ) {
    int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    ft::pointer_iterator<int, std::ptrdiff_t> iter;
    ft::pointer_const_iterator<int, std::ptrdiff_t> iter2(iter);
    ft::pointer_iterator<int, std::ptrdiff_t> iter3(iter);
    return 0;
}
```

and outputs

```
parent default constructor called
parent copy constructor called
parent copy constructor called
```

But when I uncomment the commented lines that contains a new constructor my class suddendly stops heriting from the default constructor and the line `ft::pointer_iterator<int, std::ptrdiff_t> iter;` throws an error at compilation. Why ? I didn't edit the existing code and the compiler suddendly fails to find the default constructor in the parent class.
Note: it still finds the copy constructor...

Comment: You can do `using Base::Base;` in the derived class (where `Base` is the name of base class).

Comment: @lorro will it inherit from all constructors or just the default constructor? If for example I add a constructor that takes a pointer in the parent class will it inherit too ?

Comment: The above inherits all ctors.

Comment: If you just want the default implementation of a default constructor, add `iterator() = default;`